# Modifying phone number in Objective C (in iPhone App)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSString *phoneStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone_number];
NSURL *phoneURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:phoneStr];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
[phoneURL release];
[phoneStr release];

NSString *phoneStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"tel:*12*%@",phone_number];
```

I am trying to make app for iPhone to call someone using 'Contacts' but when I touch the number I need to call like that : example; Number:12345 when I touch it , call for *12*12345#
If I want to modify the number by adding ****12**** , what should I do? 
My app crash when I did like that way :/

Comment: Post your crash log here. "My App Crash" is vague, provide as much debugging info you can when asking a question.

Comment: What type is `phone_number`? If it's an `int` then your format string should be `@"tel:%i"`

Answer (score 0):

Make it simpler and use convince methods:

```
NSString *phoneStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:*12*%@",phone_number];
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL urlWithString:phoneStr];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may reconsider using * or # symbols, because it appears Apple wont let you phone any number using the *tel:* scheme if it contains any of those.

More information here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html